# Why does the following javascript snippet produce an empty zip archive?

Tags: javascript, zip

The snippet below is using  [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/index.html) to create a zip archive, ZippyMcZip.zip or the Strings in contents. contents is an array of values. e.g.

```
{name:"my name",contents:"contents to write to file."}
```

The archive is being created, however apart from the manifest it is empty:

```
$ unzip -l ZippyMcZip.zip
Archive:  ZippyMcZip.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  05-01-13 16:41   File1.txt
        0  05-01-13 16:41   File2.txt
 --------                   -------
        0                   2 files
```

Does anyone have any pointers as to why the archive would contain empty files?

*saveAs* is provided by [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js), I don't think it is an issue as the file is being written to the HD and it being used elsewhere.

```
function createZip(contents) {      

function onProgress(a,b) {
    console.log("current",a, "end",b);
  }            

function onEnd() {
    console.log("on End");
  }            

  zip.workerScriptsPath = "/js/zip/";
  zip.useWebWorkers = false;

  var zipper = (function() {

    var zipWriter;

    return {

      addTexts: function(files) {

          function add(text) {
            zipWriter.add(text.name,
                     new zip.TextReader(text.contents),onEnd,onProgress);
          }

          zip.createWriter(new zip.BlobWriter(), function(writr) {
            zipWriter = writr;
          });              

          _.foreach(files, add);

      },
      getBlob: function(callback) {
        zipWriter.close(callback);
      }
    };
  })();

  zipper.addTexts(contents);
  zipper.getBlob(function(blob) { 
    saveAs(blob, "ZippyMcZip.zip"); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there anything missing in my response? ...

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues related to the asynchronous nature of zip.js API.

First, you try to write multiple files in parallel: it won't work. So, instead of iterating with the synchronous `_.foreach` function, you have to call the `add` function recursively in the `onEnd` callback of `zipWriter.add` method (cf. `[1]`).

Then, you also have to wait for this content to be written before calling `zipWriter.close` method, so you have to define a `callback` parameter (cf. `[2]`) in the signature of `addTexts` method. It is called when the recursive process is finished.

Here is your code with these 2 fixes:

```
function createZip(contents) {

  function onProgress(a, b) {
    console.log("current", a, "end", b);
  }

  zip.workerScriptsPath = "/js/zip/";
  zip.useWebWorkers = false;

  var zipper = (function() {

    var zipWriter;

    return {
      addTexts : function(files, callback /* [2] new parameter */) {

        function add(fileIndex) {
          if (fileIndex < files.length) {
            zipWriter.add(files[fileIndex].name, 
                new zip.TextReader(files[fileIndex].contents), function() {
              add(fileIndex + 1); /* [1] add the next file */
            }, onProgress);
          } else {
            callback() /* [2] no more files to add: callback is called */;
          }
        }

        zip.createWriter(new zip.BlobWriter(), function(writer) {
          zipWriter = writer;
          add(0); /* [1] add the first file */
        });
      },
      getBlob : function(callback) {
        zipWriter.close(callback);
      }
    };
  })();

  zipper.addTexts(contents, function() {
    zipper.getBlob(function(blob) {
      saveAs(blob, "ZippyMcZip.zip"); 
    });
  });  
}
```